# Perforce command to get a list of shelves

Tags: perforce

How do I get a list of more than 200 shelves in perforce?
Following command is listing only 200 shelves.

```
p4 changes -u <username> -s shelved
```

I tried adding `-m 500` without any change in outcome. Is it a local issue?

Comment: Is it possible that that user only has 200 shelves?  Also, what's `p4w`?  Is that a wrapper that might be rewriting (or filtering) the `p4` command?

Comment: `-m` command sets max number of results to be returned. In your case, if you get only 200 results without `-m`, that means you are getting server limited by 200 results listed per query. One quick resolution is to multiply the `p4 changes` command with a smaller limit and different starting numbers, like some sort of recursion

Comment: @Kreetchy Server-side limits aren't applied silently that way -- if you hit a limit (e.g. `MaxScanRows` or `MaxResults`), you'll receive an error message.  If you get 200 results without `-m`, it means there are only 200 results in total.